# How to attach .msg from Outlook drafts folder to another e-mail?

Tags: vba, outlook

Company policy prevents `.SaveAs` when my code drafts an e-mail with an attachment.
I save the drafts into the Outlook folder, but the goal is to attach that .msg to another message.

Is there any way via VBA to create an e-mail and add the attachment by accessing the Outlook drafts folder?

`.SaveAs` and `olSaveAsType` fail due to company policy; unable to change registry to enable prompttosaveas (Error 287).
Unable to create from template due to variable file attachment within initial message.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the existing draft item in Outlook and continue setting it up for sending from the Drafts folder. The [MailItem.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.copy) method creates another instance of an object, so the template saved in the Drafts folder will be remained as is.

```
Sub CopyItem() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts) 
 Set myItem = myFolder.Items(1)
 Set myCopiedItem = myItem.Copy 
 myCopiedItem.Send() 
 
End Sub
```

Or you just can create a brand new email item in Outlook and then attach an existing item by using the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method which creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, you just need to specify an Outlook item instance you want to be attached.

Comment: Perfect. Works for me in both instances and I'm able to complete. Just hung up on not being able to use .saveas had my head spinning. Thanks!